# Tiny-slider | Кастомизация стрелок

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Нужно кастомизировать стрелки в tiny-slider. В [документации](https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider) ничего не нашёл. Помогите, кто уже делал такое.

Вот код:

```js
var slider = tns({
    container: ".slider",
    mode: "carousel",
    slideBy: "page",
    nav: false,
    speed: 500,
    responsive: {
        320: {
            items: 1,
            gutter: 10,
            touch: true,
            mouseDrag: true,
            controls: false
        },
        900: {
            items: 3,
            touch: true,
            gutter: 20,
            mouseDrag: true,
            controls: true
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Верстаете кнопки, потом убираете стандартные через `controls: false`, и указываете селекторы кнопок кастомных в `prevButton` и `nextButton` в документации это есть

Comment: Не работает. Вот код:

Comment: var slider = tns({
    container: ".slider",
    mode: "carousel",
    slideBy: "page",
    nav: false,
    speed: 500,
    responsive: {
        320: {
            items: 1,
            gutter: 10,
            touch: true,
            mouseDrag: true,
            controls: false
        },
        900: {
            items: 3,
            touch: true,
            gutter: 20,
            mouseDrag: true,
            controls: false,
            prevButton: "<img src='images/left_yellow.png'>",
            nextButton: "<img src='images/right_yellow.png'>"
        }
    }

Comment: В том смысле, что класс или id? Или как?

Comment: в смысле селектора, который скрипт может обработать скорее всего через `querySelector` или `querySelectorAll` т.е. к примеру `prevButton: '.prev-button-class',`

Comment: Понял, сейчас проверю

Comment: .left-yellow{
        width: 100%;
        background-image: url(images/left_yellow.png);
    }
    .right-yellow{
        width: 100%;
        background-image: url(images/right_yellow.png);
    }

Comment: prevButton: ".left-yellow",
nextButton: ".right-yellow"

Comment: Не работает почему-то....

Comment: Здесь же не нужно сами теги добавлять в разметку? Просто тогда они отображаются как слайды, а ставить ```display: none```, что-то не хочется

Comment: Есть пример костомизации в [демке](http://ganlanyuan.github.io/tiny-slider/demo/) строка Customize

Comment: Не понял теперь. Это кнопки реальные должны быть. Их селектором указать в опциях